# Как использовать условие в фильтре QuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

Пытаюсь сделать с виду простую вещь: мне нужно получить из базы ключ, который удовлетворяет условию, что количество использований меньше, чем разрешённое количество использований, либо если разрешено бесконечное количество запросов (значение разрешённых запросов = -1). Количество использований считается по количеству небесплатных запросов из базы запросов и принайтовывается к запросу как аннотация. Далее идёт фильтр, который, собственно, и занимается этим грязным делом.

Пробовал сделать двумя способами: первый - закомментированный. Насколько я понял, проблема с ним была в том, что несмотря на то, что if находится внутри запроса, так как самим телом запроса не является, F() не понимает, что я от него хочу. Тогда я обратился к документации и нашёл там конструкцию Case(When()), но теперь получаю ошибку `Cannot filter against a non-conditional expression.`

```py
def getThisKey(request, active=True, free=False):
    return APIKey.objects.annotate(
        used_times=Count('APIRequests', filter=Q(APIRequests__free=False))
    ).filter(
        Q(exp_datetime__gte=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), status="Active") if active else Q(),
        # Q(used_times__lt=F('allowed_requests')) if not (free or F('allowed_requests') == -1) else Q(),
        Case(
                When(~Q(allowed_requests=-1), then=Q(used_times__lt=F('allowed_requests'))),
                default=Q()
        ),
        key=(
            request.GET['APIKey'] if request.method == "GET"
            else request.data['APIKey'],
        )
    ).first()
```

Ещё пытался обернуть Case() в Q(), но буквально ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте такое условие:

```
Q(allowed_requests=-1) | Q(used_times__lt=F('allowed_requests'))
```

`Case`/`When` тут не нужен, а используете его вы неправильно. `then` и `default` должны быть выражения, которые будут возвращаться, а не условия в QuerySet. То есть это или имя колонки или константа (`Value(...)`) или формула (`F-выражение`).